# Show multiple input textbox if checkbox are checked simultaneously as marquee

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea, html-entities, marquee

I am not experienced with this but I think I am on good way. I need help from someone experienced. Think it is interesting issue
Let's say there is 3 checkboxes and 3 textboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" value="1.">  
<textarea name="text[1]" ></textarea>

 <input type="checkbox" name="check[2]" value="2.">   
 <textarea name="text[2]" ></textarea>

 <input type="checkbox" name="check[3]" value="3.">  
 <textarea name="text[3]" ></textarea>
```

And I need to create a loop which will check foreach `check[%]` if is checked with 
`if (isset($_POST['check[%]']))` to add all checked `text[%]` textboxes values to some `$value`

`$value` needs to be output as one line in as marquee

I think it needs to be `$value` needs to go trough `html_entity_decode`  but I am not sure.
finally output to be something like

```
$output .= "<font><marquee scrollamount='3' BEHAVIOR=SCROLL DIRECTION="left"> $value"."</marquee>"."</font>";
```

Comment: If the checkboxes can be checked and unchecked when te page is already loaded, as your HTML shows me. why don't you use javascript to handle it all?

Comment: I wanted it to be clean HTML and PHP...But I was also thinking about javascript but How would you make multiple input to be shown as one marquee in javascript?

Comment: Something like `document.getElementById("your-marquee").innerHTML = marqueetext;` In a function that runs on changing the value of every checkbox, checks which checkboxes are checked and populates `var marqueetext` with the textareas. EDIT: Should also run onpageload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, for a PHP POST I would not use brackets in the name of the input values.

index.php:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1.">  
    <textarea name="text1" ></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2.">   
    <textarea name="text2" ></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="3.">  
    <textarea name="text3" ></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

test.php:

```
    $total_checkbox_num = 3;
    $final_message = '';
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($key)) {
                $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($value)));
            }
        }
        for($i = 1; $i <= $total_checkbox_num; $i++) {
            if(isset($_POST['check'.$i])) {
                $final_message .= $_POST['text'.$i];
            }
        }
        $output = '<font><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="left">' . $final_message . '</marquee></font>';
        echo $output;
    } else echo "There was an error";
```